# How do I annotate a JPA Entity to use a Date with OracleDB?

Tags: oracle, scala, jpa

I have a OracleDB column of type `Date`. I can make a JPA entity that does not include this column and everything works great. However when I try to add this column like...

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
case class MyDate(
  @Column(
      name = "MY_DATE",
  ) 
  @BeanProperty date: Timestamp
) {
  def this() {
    this(null)
  }
  ...
}
```

I get...

> ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

How do I properly annotate a JPA Date Entity using Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to accept this because I would like to do it in the constructor like I described but this does work....

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
case class MyDate() {
  @Column(
      name = "MY_DATE",
  ) 
  @BeanProperty 
  val date: Timestamp = null
  ...
}
```